# Create discount if products from two specific categories are in cart

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

I need to create a $100 discount on the cart total if products from two specific categories are added to the cart. I can only get the cart to apply the rule always -- despite the rules saying otherwise -- or not at all.

**Attempt number 1, yields no discount**
[image: Attempt number 1, yields no discount]

**Attempt number 2, gives discount regardless of cart contents**
[image: Attempt number 2, gives discount regardless of cart contents]

Answer (score 2):

Please use the following configuration:

Conditions:
[image: amasty-special-promotions-conditions]

Actions:
[image: [amasty-special-promotions-actions]